# TikZ's \foreach tuple in PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot a list of data and add according legend entries. I tried to use `\foreach` for tuples which is implemented in `pgffor` package and loaded with TikZ. Unfortunately, the second variable describing the label `\clabel` appears to be undefined for LaTeX. This construction seems to work if used outside `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}`. Do I miss something essential regarding TikZ/PGF?

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[]
      \foreach \c/\clabel in {1/a, 2/b}
      {
        \addplot  {\c^2};
        \addlegendentry{ \clabel }
      };
    \end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand `\clabel` as the argument for `\addlegendentry`, since the legend itself is created after the plots are complete.  By that point, the local value of `\clabel` has been lost.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[]
      \foreach \c/\clabel in {1/a, 2/b}
      {
        \addplot  {\c^2};
        \expandafter\addlegendentry\expandafter{\clabel};
      }
    \end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]